# Configure Resource "aws_cloud_distribution" with ec2 as the origin with Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting up a "aws_cloud_distribution" with Terraform and attempting to set an ec2 as my origin.

In my module I have:

```
origin {
    domain_name = var.domain_name
    origin_id = var.origin_id
  }
```

In the main file I call this module and use the output of the ec2 public dns.

```
module "cloudfront" {
  source = "./modules/cloudfront"

  domain_name = module.ec2.ec2_public_dns

  origin_id = "myid"

  target_origin_id = "myid"
}
```

When I run plan, I have no issues. However when I run apply and begin the build process I get the following error:

> error creating CloudFront Distribution: InvalidArgument: The parameter
> Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.
> status code: 400

I am using terraform 0.13.6 out of some company restrictions to other infra in the company. Is this a Terraform version issue or am I missing something in my configuration steps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I figured out this issue by adding the `custom_origin_config` argument within the origin argument. The solution looks like the following:

```
origin {
    domain_name = var.domain_name
    origin_id = var.origin_id
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port = 80
      https_port = 443
      origin_protocol_policy = "match-viewer"
      origin_ssl_protocols = ["TLSv1"]
    }
  }
```

Terraform defaults to S3 origin if you don't define the custom_origin_config argument. The AWS plugin for Terraform is searching for an s3 bucket and not an AWS FQDN to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with `aws_cloudfront_distribution` -

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "origin_access_identity" {

}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cdn_distribution" {
    origin {
        domain_name                   = aws_instance.ec2_instance.public_dns
        origin_id                     = "${local.origin_id}"
        custom_origin_config {
            http_port                 = 80
            https_port                = 80
            origin_protocol_policy    = "http-only"
            origin_ssl_protocols      = ["TLSv1"]
        }
    }

    enabled                           = true
    # is_ipv6_enabled                   = true
    aliases                           = ["${var.subdomain_name}.${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name}"]

    default_cache_behavior {
        # allowed_methods         = ["HEAD", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        allowed_methods               = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        cached_methods                = ["HEAD", "GET"]
        target_origin_id              = "${local.origin_id}"

    forwarded_values {
        query_string                  = true
        headers                       = ["Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
        cookies {
            forward                   = "none"
        }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy            = "redirect-to-https"
        min_ttl                       = 0
        default_ttl                   = 3600
        max_ttl                       = 86400
    }

    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
            restriction_type          = "none"
            }
    }

    price_class                       = "${var.cloudfront_price_class}"

    viewer_certificate {
        # cloudfront_default_certificate  = true
        ssl_support_method            = "sni-only"
        acm_certificate_arn           = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.certificate.arn}"
    }

    tags = {
        description                   = "${var.component_name}-cdn"
        Name                          = "${var.component_name}-cdn"
        app                           = "${var.common_value}"
    }
}
```

Many thanks to @keimille, his answer got me here.